# When to use The First & Second Conditional?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If I knew the answer, I would tell you.
>
> If I know the answer, I will tell you.

I totally understand both sentence, but I am confused when to use them.
For example; if someone asking me about the answer why would I say the first conditional, and why would I say the second one?

Comment: It depends on whether or not you know the answer.

Comment: First type is used to predict a result, or once the first clause is triggered, the consequent action will take place at some point in the future. Second type is used for unreal present situations.

Comment: "If I know the answer, I will tell you" doesn't make sense. " I don't know the answer, so I can't tell you." is the idea. "When I know the answer I will tell you." would work.

Comment: How do you say and use those if-sentences (with real and unreal condition) in your mother tongue?

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [English conditional sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences) which discusses first conditional, second conditional, third conditional, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence ("if I know") is rather unlikely to be said, and if it were said, it would probably be interpreted with future meaning (i.e. "if at some time in the future I know the answer").

The first sentence implies that you do not know the answer, and therefore will not tell you.